# Run services as different processes

Tags: windows-services

I have five Windows services that all exist in the same exe. Is there a way to tell Windows to run each service as it's own process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. See [the CreateService API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682450(VS.85).aspx)

Note the SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS flag.

Comment: It appears you are right, but I dread the idea of ripping out my installer logic (.NET based) and switching to p/invoke calls. Oh well, there are other things I don't like about the .NET service installer anyways, so maybe this is the right time to fix all of that.

Comment: I empathize.  I wonder if you put each service in it's own IServiceContainer, tell each service config to be a different name, and then run svcutil for each piece separately what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use background worker threads?

Comment: Well yea, pretty much all services run that way. My goal is to increase the isolation level so a failure in one doesn't bring the others down.